# Accessing button from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms each with buttons, textboxes, and labels. In form1 I have a this code in a button event handler:

```
 frmTwo form = new frmTwo ();
 form.Show();
 this.Visible = false; //closing form 1 when frmTwo opens
```

I went to the designer file for frmTwo and changed all of the controls: labels, textboxes, buttons from private (which was auto generated) to public.

Under this line of code: `this.Visible = false;` I want to put an if statement to check if a name textbox in frmTwo is blank. But when I write txtName.Text it says the textbox doesn't exist in the current context. I understand why it doesn't exist because its inside frmTwo NOT from1. But I'm not sure what other ways I can access this textbox because I already made it public in the designer. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What will you then do if the textbox in form2 is blank? It should be something form2 checks and handles, really, perhaps in it's Shown event. In OO programming we don't really write code in such a way that it reaches into other objects and fiddles around with them if we can help it; it's in the aim of reducing how much eg form1 depends on form2; form2 should look after its own problems :)

Comment: If you want to control visibility of controls on a form it is better to create a _single_ public method that controls it, than to try to deal with each individual control externally of the form.

Comment: You need to use the reference to the form you created, which is "frmTwo".  So you'd use `frmTwo.txtName.Text`.  ...BUT...as the others have pointed out, this is of little value because it will run immediately after the form is displayed, and the user will not have had time to enter anything in the TextBox.  If you want your form to WAIT for the other form to be "done", then you most likely want to display it with `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`.  The former will cause the current form code to STOP until the new form is dismissed.

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))**

Comment: You reference the form instance first: `form.txtName.Text`

Comment: @Idle_Mind `frmTwo` was the type, `form` was the new variable name.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself: Is it important for form1 that the information that you want to read from form2 is in a textbox? Would form1 really care if the same information would be kept by form2 in a ComboBox?

Wouldn't it be best if form1 doesn't know how form2 gets the information? All it has to know is that form2 is willing to provide the information. If form2 needs to read it from a database, or fetch it from the internet to fetch the information, why would form1 care? All form1 wants to know: "Hey Form2, give me information X"

Alas you didn't tell us if you want this information only once, or that form1 needs to be kept informed whenever information X changes. Let's assume that you do.

So, class Form2 will have a method to provide information X, and it is willing to tell everyone that information X is changed. Form2 does not show to the outside world how it gets its information. The current version holds information X in the text of TextBox1. Future versions might read it from a ComboBox, or read if from a file, or from the internet.

```
class Form2 : System.Windows.Window
{
    public event EventHandler XChanged;

    public string X
    {
        // information X is in textBox1
        get => this.textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void TextBox1_Changed(object sender, ...)
    {
        // the text in textBox1 changed, so information X changed
        this.OnXChanged();
    }

    protected virtual void OnXChanged()
    {
        this.XChanged?.Invoke(new Eventhandler(this, EventArgs.Empty));
    }

    ... // other Form2 methods
}
```

Now if Form1 wants to know the value of X, it can simply ask for it:

```
Form2 form2 = ...
string informationX = form2.X;
```

If Form1 wants to be kept informed whenever information X changes:

```
form2.XChanged += InformationXChanged;

private void InformationXChanged(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = (Form2)sender;

    // get the new information X from form2:
    string informationX = form2.X;
    this.ProcessInformationX(informationX);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one form to replace the other, then you pass a reference to `Form1` in the `.Show()` of `Form2` and the form stores it in the `.Owner` property. The when the second form starts it will hide the first form. Additionally, when the second form closes it can unhide the first form.

<sub>Please use Capitalized names for types like `Form` and pascalCase for variables like `mainForm = new Form()`.</sub>

### Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show(this);
    }
}
```

### Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.FormClosing += Form2_FormClosing;
        this.Owner.Visible = false;
    }
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Owner.Visible = true;
    }

    public bool IsNameBlank { get => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text); }
}
```

This is the basic framework. I also added some logic where `Form1` checks for a textBox in `Form2`. Add a property in `Form2` that returns the check:

and access it form `From1`

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show(this);

        if (f2.IsNameBlank)
        { 
            // textBox is empty.
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could just pass the reference via `Show()` itself, like `f2.Show(this);`, then in Form2 you can access the reference via the [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner?view=netcore-3.1) property.  This way you don't have to create a separate constructor just to receive Form1.

Comment: Good point. I will make changes. But then I need to hook on `OnLoad()` in order to hide the first form.